# Unity CharacterController not colliding with all objects

Tags: unity-game-engine

My player has a CharacterController that I am using to detect collisions. My platform has a BoxCollider and a standard RigidBody and collides with my player just fine.

I've made it so the user can draw lines during run-time, but I can't get the collisions between them and the player to trigger. The custom user lines are called LineObjects in the hierarchy and they each generate with a LineRenderer component and an EdgeCollider2D component whose points are set to the same points used to create LineRenderer.

[Unity Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAxBb.png)

[Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ixrV.png)

Comment: Does your platform has BoxCollider or BoxCollider2D ?

Comment: Platform is just BoxCollider

Comment: Probably that's why. Your character controller can collide with 3d colliders not 2d colliders.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. Thanks!

Comment: Also I see that the IsTrigger is set to true, have you tried setting this to false?

Comment: You have IsTrigger set to True.